# How to fix black screen after install nvidia driver?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I got a new laptop (Asus G75VX) with a Geforce G70MX card.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on it and it works, but when I try to go and install the Nvidia driver from the *update system*, when I reboot there is only a black screen.

I am new to Ubuntu so I don't know how to fix this problem neither how to get a log with what went wrong on the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem might be with optimus. It means your pc has 2 graphic cards, one this NVIDIA and second is Intels integrated card. If so, you should take a look at [bumblebee-project](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) because linux does not support nvidia drivers, as far as i know. Guess you should reinstall ubuntu and this time avoid installing NVIDIA drivers, but instead install bumblebee, otherwise pc would heat a lot. Hope I helped.

Actually I think you can test for optimus by writing:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

in console. If it shows intel and nvidia controllers like:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor       Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

then you have optimus.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "Ctrl + Alt + F2" to enter the recovery console. Then use

```
sudo apt-get remove <driver name>
```

Then try

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304-stable
```

as I know the 304 version worked for me